# How to find $\angle{EAD}$ in the given figure?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

(It is not a homework problem! It was asked in one of my friends' placement related entrance examination this year.)

**My work:** Assuming $\angle{EAD}=\angle{\mathbf{1}}=x,$ it is clear that $\angle{ODB}=x$ since $\angle{AEB}=90^\circ,$ being a semi-circular angle.

(Now if I consider $BC$ to be a tangent to the circle at $B,$ then using all the known facts we can find $\angle{ACB}$ as well as $\angle{DAO}.$ But still I am not able to find $x.$)

Although it is not mentioned that $BC$ is a tangent so considering $BC$ to be a secant, I am not able to make use of the fact that $OB=BC.$ (I think I should not consider $BC$ as a tangent.) Either way I am stuck basically.

Please give some hints to make use of the fact: $OB=BC$ for finding $x.$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hints: Drop the perpendicular BH of B onto line AC, with $H$ belonging to the circle: we get BH = 2 DO. Besides, use Pythagoras theorem in triangle ABC to express $AC$ as a function of $R$ (the radius of the circle).

Comment: If you don't know BC is tangent, then BC = OB gives no information to find $x$

Comment: Thank you both Jean Marie and Ivan Kaznacheyeu sir for your comments. These helped a lot for me to find $x$.

Comment: @Jean Marie Sir how did you realize that if $BF\bot AC$ is drawn then our job will be done? I mean while solving geometry problems I get confused what and where should I make a construction so that the goal is achieved. While solving this problem on my own I was thinking of a construction but wasn't really sure where to construct actually. Any tip regarding how to overcome such confusions quickly and effectively?

Comment: @Usual_Learner Please don't be discouraged by my down vote, it is not for you but for the problem. Because of its inaccurate wording, it wasted much of my time (and yours and other people's here). Please see details in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I am assuming $BC$ is tangent to the circle as you mentioned in your work.

We have $\triangle ADO \sim \triangle ABC$

Also, $\triangle ADO \sim \triangle AFB$

Using similarity, what is the relation between $BF$ and $FD$?

Finally note that $x = \angle FBD$

Comment: Great answer but I have one doubt which is how do we know that the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ will lie on the circle, namely at $F$?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee $AB$ is a diameter of the circle and hence $AB$ will subtend an angle of $90^\circ$ at all points on the perimeter.

Comment: Ohh yes yes correct.. Dumb/blind me!

Comment: @Math Lover Thank you sir. Following your approach I could deduce that $BF=FD$ and hence $x=45^\circ.$

Comment: @Usual_Learner yes that is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $CB$ tangent at $B$ (see @Ivan Kaznacheyeu comment), then join $CO$.[image: How to find angle EAD]

Since $BCDO$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, and right triangle $COB$ is isosceles, then$$\angle COB=45^o$$But $$\angle CDB=\angle COB$$since they stand on common arc $CB$.

Hence$$\angle EDA=\angle CDB=45^o$$Therefore right triangle $ADE$ is also isosceles and$$\angle EAD=45^o$$

Comment: Wow! All of you make these problems look so easy by providing simply elegant solutions. I can't choose which answer to "accept" basically and so I won't.

Comment: Sir one question: Which soft ware did you use to draw the figure you have given here? Although in this approach, we do not have to draw $BF\bot AC.$

Comment: I used GeoGebra for the figure, which I have edited in light of your observation that $BF$ is not used in the argument and so is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I respectfully disagree with Math Lover, Edward, and OP's assumption of tangency of $BC$ to the large circle. Below, I first explain the construction, then I show with an example that the problem indeed lacks sufficient information, then I give a general guideline for solving the problem. I will conclude with remarks about the problem.

**1.Construction**

Reproducing the construction helps us better understand the problem. We can start from the large circle with center $O$ and radius $OA$. Let's call it the main circle.

1. Within the main circle, draw $Circle1$ with diameter $OA$.
2. From $B$ draw a line such that it intersects (or touches) $Circle1$. Let this line first meet $Circle1$ at $D$ and then meet the main circle at $E$. Already we have constructed the angles $\widehat{AEB}=\widehat{ODA}=90^o$ (why?) and the unknown angle $\widehat{EAD}$, the measure of which we wish to find.
3. Draw $Circle2$ with center $B$ and radius $OB$.
4. Extend $AD$ to meet (or touch) $Circle2$. Name the furthest meeting point of this extension as $C$.

[image]

**2.Information**

The above figure shows two examples of the construction. In the lower example, $BC$ is tangent to the main circle. Note that

1. $\widehat{EAD}$ measures differently in the two examples. This means that the problem in its current wording does not have a unique answer. Comparing the measures with the multiple choices of the problem shows that the designers of the problem had *assumed* that $BC$ is tangent to the main circle, but they did not mention this assumption in the problem. Therefore, the problem lacks information necessary for the intended solution.
2. The construction of the angle $\widehat{EAD}$ was completed without any regard to point $C$. In the problem as it is worded, especially without mentioning the constraint of tangency of $BC$ to the main circle, the information given about $BC$ and $C$ is useless.

**3.General guideline**

The interested reader can solve the problem using analytic geometry, and find the measure of $\widehat{EAD}$ based on $\widehat{EBA}$, which defines the slope of the line $BE$, which was arbitrarily drawn in step 2 of the construction (considering the only constraint that it should meet $Circle1$). The general steps are:

1. Write the equations of the main circle, $Circle1$ and $BE$
2. Find $D$, the intersection of $BE$ and $Circle1$.
3. Find $E$, the intersection of $BE$ and the main circle.
4. Calculate the angle between $AD$ and $AE$.

**4.Conclusion**

Designers of the problem failed to mention all of the assumptions that they had when designing the problem. Without the particular assumption of tangency of $BC$ to the main circle, the question has an infinite number of answers. Moreover, without this assumption, the information given about point $C$ is useless. I was only able to figure out the assumptions of the designers from the multiple choices of the question. This is an example of a bad question that wastes the time of everyone who works on it. Therefore, while I respect the efforts made by the OP, I give a down vote to the question itself. I hope my act encourages OP and other MSE members to create for themselves some sort of a blacklist of sources that are not worthy of our time and effort.

Comment: @ACB Oh my! Thanks for telling me, I'll edit that part. I mixed up names of MSE members that I respect! As for the circles, the two that were added to the main figure are shown with dashed lines, so as to show added components while avoiding visual complexity.

Comment: Thank you sir for giving your precious time. It was helpful and interesting indeed. I believe you typed CIRCLE 2 instead of CIRCLE 1 in step 2 under the construction section. I have understood all of your points. After seeing this problem for the first time I was pondering whether $BC$ is a tangent or some secant to the main circle and so at first I considered $BC$ as a secant and started to work with it but I didn't try to make use of my knowledge of co-ordinate geometry as a result was unable to reach any conclusion. But, your general guideline has demonstrated the same. Thanks...

Comment: @Usual_Learner Thank you for your comment, and thanks for correcting my mistake. I edited that part of the post. Like you, I spent much time looking for a solution using Euclidean geometry. It's a pity question designers ignored required information and confused us all. But in the effort, other things were revealed. For an interesting example: draw a line passing through $B$ and the midpoint of $OC$, and let it intersect the main circle at $F$. Then $OBCF$ is a rhombus!